# Decimal field not behaving as expected in CRM

Tags: c#, crm

I wrote a CRM plugin that updates a custom field of type Decimal, by taking the product price and multiplying it by the quantity.

For some reason the update never happened. I always find the product price value.

For example:

```
Product price = 100
Quantity = 10
Custom field = Product price * quantity = 100
```

If I tried to do some addition instead, like Custom field = Product price + 3 it works.

To make it work:

```
Decimal total = quantity * priceDiscServiceContract.Price;

oppProduct.custom_prediscountamount = total;

for (int i = 0; i < quantity-1; i++)
{
    oppProduct.custom_prediscountamount += total;
}
```

I managed to get the right value, but what the code is doing is beyond any logic.
Am i missing some properties of the Decimal type?

I created the custom field myself today so I am sure there are no other plugins firing on it.

The code of the execution method is:

```
mailSubject = "Marco's code: " + this.GetType().Name + " class in the " + context.OrganizationName + " organization";
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieving Opp product");
//retrieve the entity product as the input Entity
var entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

//Early bound entity
oppProduct = new opportunityproduct(entity);
//exit if the user wants to use custom price
if (oppProduct.custom_ispriceoverridden == true)
    return;
var quantity = (Decimal)oppProduct.quantity;
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieving Opp with opp ID = {0}" + oppProduct.opportunityid.Id.ToString());

//get the early bound opportunity containing the opportunity product
var opp = new opportunity(Helpers.ActualEntity(oppProduct.opportunityid, service));
//get the early bound account entity that is the customer for the opportunity
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieved, type = {0}" + opp.name);
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieving Account with accountID={0}" + opp.customerid.Id.ToString());
Entity acc = Helpers.ActualEntity(opp.customerid, service, new String[] { "accountnumber", "dynamics_integrationkey" });
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Account retrieved");
var account = new account(acc);
//get the ax integration key for the account
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieving Account AX key");
var accountNumber = account.accountnumber;
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieving Product");
//get the early bound account entity that is the customer for the opportunity
var prod = new product(Helpers.ActualEntity(oppProduct.productid, service, new string[] { "productnumber" }));
//get the integration key for the product
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Retrieving Product AX key");
var productNumber = prod.productnumber;

Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Invoking web service");

if (account.dynamics_integrationkey == null || account.dynamics_integrationkey == "")
{
    PriceWithNoAccountNumber priceWithNoAccountNumber = new PriceWithNoAccountNumber
    {
        ProductNumber = prod.productnumber,
        Quantity = quantity,
        GroupId = account.custom_salesgroup.ToString(),
        LineDiscountCode = account.custom_linediscount.ToString(),
        CurrencyCode = opp.transactioncurrencyidname
    };
    priceDiscServiceContract = Helpers.GetPriceDiscServiceContract(service, tracingService, priceWithNoAccountNumber);
}
else
{
    PriceWithAccountNumber priceWithAccountNumber = new PriceWithAccountNumber
    {
        ProductNumber = prod.productnumber,
        AccountNumber = account.accountnumber,
        Quantity = quantity
    };
    priceDiscServiceContract = Helpers.GetPriceDiscServiceContract(service, tracingService, priceWithAccountNumber);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(priceDiscServiceContract.ErrorTxt))
{
    Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage, "GetPriceDiscServiceContract returned an error.");
    return;
}
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,priceDiscServiceContract.ToString());



Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage," ");
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Price : " + priceDiscServiceContract.Price);
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"Markup : " + priceDiscServiceContract.Markup);
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"PriceUnit : " + priceDiscServiceContract.PriceUnit);
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage,"DiscAmount : " + priceDiscServiceContract.DiscAmount);
Helpers.AddToTraceAndError(tracingService, errorMessage, "DiscPct : " + priceDiscServiceContract.DiscPct);

oppProduct.isproductoverridden = false;

//throw new Exception("Quantity = " + quantity + ", priceperunit = " + priceDiscServiceContract.Price + ", quantity * priceperunit = " + total );
oppProduct.custom_discountamount = priceDiscServiceContract.DiscPct;// priceDiscServiceContract.DiscPct;
oppProduct.priceperunit = priceDiscServiceContract.LineAmount;

Decimal totalMoney = quantity * priceDiscServiceContract.Price;

Decimal total = quantity * priceDiscServiceContract.Price;

oppProduct.custom_prediscountamount = total;

for (int i = 0; i < quantity - 1; i++)
{
    oppProduct.custom_prediscountamount += total;
}

double convertedDiscountPercent = 0;
Double.TryParse(priceDiscServiceContract.DiscPct.ToString(), out convertedDiscountPercent);
oppProduct.custom_discountpercent = convertedDiscountPercent;
```

Comment: In what way does 100 * 10 = 100?

Comment: When I write oppProduct.custom_prediscountamount = quantity * priceDiscServiceContract.Price; the value I get is always priceDiscServiceContract.Price, even when I try to put a hardcoded value instead of quantity

Comment: It is as if you desire `price * quantity * quantity`. Your loop adds `total` to the value `(quantity-1)` times, and there already was one `total` in that value from the beginning.

Comment: I know, it doesn't make sense

Comment: Did you create this code or are you trying to interpret someone else's code? It sounds like both from your question and answers to the comments.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Step 1 - Verify that you don't have more then one plugin firing. Step 2 - post the full code of the plugin.

Comment: @Klors the code is mine, I have been making so many attempts that at the end I got it working, even if I don't know why.  I don't dare to push this code into the repository, let alone deploying it into prod

Comment: Even if the plugin was registered on the OnCreate message, the plugin registered on the OnUpdate was triggered as well (Probably by the very OnCreate one). A fix is described here http://pierobond.postach.io/not-allow-plugins-to-run-on-update-after-the-update-on-the-oncreate-stage-of-another-plugin